# Using one main.xml for different activities action bar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am developing an app in which i show buttons on action bar. What i am doing now just adding items into **main.xml** under **menu** folder.But i so what if add 3 items in **main.xml** so if inflate **main.xml** of any activity it shows me 3 items but i want only one item so is there any way by which i don't have to create different xml files.

**following is the code:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/** define action for the action bar button*/
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_enter, R.anim.slide_exit);
        break;

    case R.id.action_create:

        fname=et_fname.getText().toString();
        lname=et_lname.getText().toString();
        email=et_email.getText().toString();
        password=et_password.getText().toString();
        IsValid();

        break;



    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is by using groups in your menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <group
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_group">
         <item android:id="@+id/action_create"
              android:title="Create"
              android:icon="R.drawable.ic_action_create"
              android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

then,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_actionbar, menu);
         menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.main_menu_group,true);
     }
 }
```

Comment: but i want only one item visible at a time from group

Comment: try this `@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem test1 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_test1);
        test1.setVisible(false);
       MenuItem test2=menu.findItem(R.id.action_test2);
      test2.setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }`